# Translate Angular-UI pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I translate text in Bootstrap UI pagination directive?

I've overrided the constants like this for french translation:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .constant('paginationConfig', {
        itemsPerPage: 10,
        boundaryLinks: false,
        directionLinks: true,
        firstText: 'Premier',
        previousText: 'Précédent',
        nextText: 'Suivant',
        lastText: 'Dernier',
        rotate: true
    })
```

But overriding constants seems to be a bad idea...

What is the correct way (if any) to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than overiding the whole constant object you can modify properties of it within the `run` method

```
var app=angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.run(function(paginationConfig){
   paginationConfig.firstText='MY FIRST';
   paginationConfig.previousText='YOUR TEXT';

})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/D55JgFQJAktY3kk5zyXW?p=preview)**</kbd>

In new version of `ui.bootstrap` you should use

```
uibPaginationConfig
```

insted of

```
paginationConfig
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried app.run before asking the question, but I forgot to inject paginationConfig like an idiot.

Comment: don't feel bad... I learned something to by doing this...plenty of hurdles along the angular learning curve

Comment: Hi Charlietfl, I am facing same issue. With your solution I am able to translate pagination text. But what if my language selection is dynamic so how can I use translate directive in such scenario?

Comment: @dip suggest you create a new question if you don't find similar one

Answer (score 7):

> Settings can be provided as attributes in the `<uib-pagination>` or globally configured through the uibPaginationConfig.

For example:

```
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap']).config(['uibPaginationConfig',
                                           function(uibPaginationConfig){
uibPaginationConfig.previousText="‹";
uibPaginationConfig.nextText="›";
uibPaginationConfig.firstText="«";
uibPaginationConfig.lastText="»";}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using the ui.bootstrap.pagination together with the angular-translate module (thanks to [@PascalPrecht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531806/pascalprecht) for this great library). However one issue which prevents the dynamic update is the used [One-time binding expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) in the default template 'template/pagination/pagination.html'. So I used the 'template-url' attribute of the [pagination directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination) to use a modified pagination template without one-time binding.

Answer (score 1):

You could use angular-translate's components to achieve this. https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

Comment: How? Could you give an example of how one can achieve this with your extension?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
$translateChangeSuccess event on $rootScope.

var $translate = $filter('translate');

$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess' , function(){
    paginationConfig.firstText = $translate('First');
    paginationConfig.lastText = $translate('Last');
    paginationConfig.previousText = $translate('Previous');
    paginationConfig.nextText = $translate('Next');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you look inside directive you can see directive parameters :

```
scope: {
  totalItems: '=',
  firstText: '@',
  previousText: '@',
  nextText: '@',
  lastText: '@',
  ngDisabled:'='
}
```

So you can pass directive parameter like below:

```
<pagination ng-if="logs" max-size="10"
    force-ellipses="true"
    boundary-links="true"
    first-text="{{translated-word}}"
    last-text="{{translated-word}}"
    next-text="{{translated-word}}"
    previous-text="{{translated-word}}"
    class="pagination-sm">
</pagination>
```