# translate angular-ui's pagination text angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-translate

i'm been working one a webpage where i use angularjs and angular-ui. And i use the pagination from angular-ui.
Now i need to change the next and previous button text after what language $translate are assigned to.
I tried to do it inline like this

```
 <pagination previous-text="{{'PREVIOUS' | translate}}" </pagination>
```

I also try doing it from my controller, but still no luck.

But it seems like i can't ref to the translate scope.
Anyone that have done something similar

--- Update ---

Think i need to something like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19608973/1866676)
.
But then the qustion is. how can i ref to the translatesion here like i do in the above code.

it's something like thie?

```
paginationConfig.previousText = 'PREVIOUS' | translate;
```

Or like this?

```
paginationConfig.previousText = 'PREVIOUS' | $translateProvider;
```

does this make anysens to you guys? or do i have to explain in a other way

Comment: Is the `||` a typo? You invoke filters with 1 `|`.

Comment: yes. sry about that. was in a hurry

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug in a plunker or a fiddle ?

Comment: @Okazari It's gonna take a little time to do this, and i'm at work right now, so i can't do it right now. but if the question ain't answered before i get home, i will try to reproduce the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure why i can't ref to the translation module inline the pagination tags
but if i inject the translation module into my controller, i can then look up the values an insert them into a scope variable, and then ref to it from html

Like shown below

Angular/Controller

```
$scope.previousText;
$scope.nextText;

$translate(['PREVIOUS', 'NEXT']).then(function (translations) {
    $scope.previousText = translations.PREVIOUS;
    $scope.nextText = translations.NEXT;
});
```

Html

```
<pagination previous-text="{{previousText}}" next-text="{{nextText}}"></pagination>
```

And it works.
Anyway, I'm gonna let this hang for a couple of days, and if no one comes up with the theory that explains this after the time limit, i'm gonna accepted this.
Thanks you all for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Have you added all your translations to the $translationProvider?

```
app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    PREVIOUS: 'previous',
  });
  $translateProvider.translations('de', {
    PREVIOUS: 'vorherige',
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});
```

Sorry, I'm not allowed to comment...

Comment: Yes i have. But what i can understand so far is that pagination from the angular-ui can't translate the previous-text and next-text inline like shown in the code sample above.